# Why is a function $g$ surjective if its composition with an injective function $s$ forms an identity function $id_K$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove the surjectivity of a function $g : N \to K$ when its composition ($g \circ s$) with an injective function $s : K \to N$ equals the identity $id_K$, but I can't seem to figure out how  the identity function helps show that $s(K) = N$ therefore $g(s(K)) = g(N) =K$ which proves that $g$ is surjective.

Also, wouldn't $s(K) = N$ show that $s$ is surjective rather than injective?

Comment: How do you know that $s(K)=N$? One great thing to do is put some concrete sets. Say, $N=\{0,1\}$ and $K=\{3\}$.

Comment: That would assume knowledge of what the functions actually are, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, and the question only specified that $g$ as a certain property...

Comment: Perhaps I should have been a bit more specific in my question, but I'm trying to come up with a proof without knowledge of what the functions map onto ($x \mapsto x^2$ for example) and only while working with certain properties of the functions and their implications, which, and excuse my relative lack of experience, seems like what mathematical proofs are all about. Either that, or I have totally misunderstood what you mean.

Comment: Yes, that is clear. I guess I should have been a bit clearer about my comment. I am challenging your comment. (See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method).)

Comment: Alright, so I'm assuming that no knowledge of the function's argument would still let me work with the content of $N$ and $K$, but how is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injectivity of $s$ is irrelevant here. If $g \circ s = \text{id}_K$ for any $s: K \rightarrow N$ then $g$ is surjective.

If $k \in K$ then there exists an $n \in N$ such that $g(n) = k$, just take $n = s(k)$, then $g(n) = g(s(k)) = k$.

Comment: Thanks. If there were no $n \in N$ with $g(n)=k$ then $g \circ s \neq id_K$, right?

Comment: Yes because that would mean that $g$ isn't surjective so $g \circ s$ can't equal $id_K$ since if they were equal $g$ would be surjective.

Answer (score 1):

The identity is surjective, so every element of $K$ is in the image of $\operatorname{id}_K$. Given that $\operatorname{id}_K=g\circ s$, the image of $\operatorname{id}_K$ is contained in the image of $g$. It follows that the image of $g$ is also $K$, and so $g$ is surjective.

Put differently; suppose that $g$ is *not* surjective. Then there is some $k\in K$ that is not in the image of $g$. Then it is also not in the image of $g\circ s$. But $g\circ s=\operatorname{id}_K$, which is surjective, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. If I were to symbolically formulate this into a proof, I assume it would look like this or is there some mistake here?:
$\lnot(\forall n,n' \in N: g(n)=g(n') \Rightarrow n=n')$
$\Rightarrow (\exists k \in K \forall n \in N: g(n) \neq k)$
$\Rightarrow (\not\exists n \in N: n = s(k))$
$\Rightarrow (g \circ s \neq id_K )$
I realize this is not a rigorous proof, but I'd greatly appreciate advice on how to go from this onto better and more coherent proofs. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm really hesitant to try to decipher that string of symbols. Usually the purpose of a proof is to convince the reader of the truth of some statement. Often that is done much more clearly with words than with symbols. A proof without words is simply a pain, to be honest.

Comment: Upon frowning deeply, the first part before the implication looks like it means *"If $g$ is not injective then..."*. But what has injectivity got to do with anything?

Comment: After squinting hard I think your string of symbols starts
$$\text{If $g$ is not injective then $g$ is not surjective then ...},$$
which is of course nonsense.

Comment: It is. I meant to write the axiom for surjectivity.. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Take a $k\in K$, you have to show that exists $n\in N$ such that $g(n)=k$. Let's take $n=s(k)$: since $g\circ s = id_K$ you have:
$$
g(n) = g(s(k)) = id_K(k) = k
$$
And this prove that $g$ is surjective.

It's not necessary true in your hypotesis that $s(K)=N$: take for example $N=\{1,2\}$, $K=\{1\}$, $g:N\rightarrow K$ s.t. $g(1)=g(2)=1$ and $s:K\rightarrow N$ s.t. $s(1)=1$. Now you have $g\circ s = id_K$, but $s(K)$ is proper contained in $N$.

Remark: In the proof we don't need the hypotesis of $s$ injective. Moreover, you can show that if $g\circ s = id_K$, than $s$ is injective.

Comment: Thanks. If there is no $n = s(k)$ then it means that $g \circ s$ can't equal $id_K$ so there has to be at least one n with $n = s(k)$ and this essentially proves that g is surjective, am I getting this correctly?

Comment: Well, you have to think quite differently. You have to fix $k\in K$ and try to find $n\in N$ such that $g(n)=k$. So $n$ is not fixed and you can choose it as you want. In our case you can choose $n=s(k)$ that exists and it is well defined because $k$ is given and what you do is just apply the function $s$ to $k$ and named the element $s(k)$ with the name $n$.

Comment: So $k$ has to be fixed because $K$ is the domain and image of the identity function, right? In order for the identity to actually be the identity, it simply has to contain $s(K)$ with no regard to any 'leftover' values of $N$, or am I wrong? Thanks for the help!